# Can't figure out why angularJS module won't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui router and angular js so when I test the app, I just get a blank screen with an injector:module error. This is the link to the error:

> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…dflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.3.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350

Here is my app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'firebase']);

// Creating fireref instance
app.factory('FireRef', function($firebase){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://dablog.firebaseio.com/');
    return ref;
});

// Creating fireauth instance
app.factory('FireAuth', function($firebaseAuth){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://dablog.firebaseio.com/');
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/site/home');
    $stateProvider
    .state('site', {
        url: '/site',
        templateUrl: 'partials/site.html'
    })
    .state('site.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    })
    .state('site.about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'
    })
    .state('site.projects', {
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html'
    })
    .state('site.blog', {
        url: '/blog',
        templateUrl: 'partials/blog.html'
        // controller: 'BlogCtrl'
    })
    .state('site.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'
        // controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('site.newpost', {
        url: '/newpost',
        templateUrl: 'partials/newpost.html',
        // controller: 'NewPostCtrl'
    })
    .state('site', {
        url: '/contact',
        templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html'
    });
})
```

Here is my blog.js file where it says "app is not defined":

```
'use strict'

app.controller('BlogCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseArray, FireRef, $state){
    var data = $firebaseArray(FireRef);
    $scope.posts = data;

    $scope.$watch('posts', function(newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.posts = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    })

    $scope.login = function() {
        $state.go('site.login');
    }

    $scope.newPost = function(){
        $state.go('site.newPost');
    }
});
```

Here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset= "utf-8">

        <title>Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Angular -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular UI Router -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular Animate -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.13/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Firebase -->
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/BlogCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/NewPostCtrl.js"></script>

        <!-- App -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Styling -->
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have declared 'use strict', so the app variable is undefined. You need to add

`var app = angular.module('myApp');`

to the top of BlogCtrl.js

Also, move `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` so that it's before the controller scripts in index.html. Because you load app.js after BlogCtrl.js, the module defined in app.js is not available in BlogCtrl.js.

Comment: When I replace 'use strict' with the variable declaration, it consoles out another "injector:nomod" error. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: Using 'use strict' is a good thing - you can leave it there. Have you included app.js in index.html above blog.js? Also, using the non-minified version of angular would give you better error info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include this line at the top of `blog.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

Edited to remove the second parameter: `, []`.

Comment: Do not add the second parameter as the module is already defined. it should be `var app = angular.module('myApp');`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I do want to add information:  do not add `var app = angular.module('myApp', [])` in blog.js, because the brackets initialize a new app, so Angular will think you're creating a new app and will throw an error, since 'myApp' already exists.  Be sure to use `var app = angular.module('myApp')` instead.  Also be sure to link the the .js file in your index file after Angular has been loaded.

Comment: I added the first one but I still receive a "nomod" error. Also I just edited my question to include my index.html file if that helps to point out any sort of linking error.